# How to download specific file on AWS Glacier Archive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I have uploaded 10 MB of archive on AWS Glacier but if i want to download specific file on that archive for example i want to download myfile.txt . is that is possible on AWS Glacier ?

Comment: Have you seen this AWS doc [Downloading an Archive in Amazon Glacier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/downloading-an-archive.html)?

Comment: Yes , of course ....

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply....but i don't get how to download specific file among archive ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, i tried Range Retrival for download specific range ... as well as limit parameter to limited download , but what i say, Download particular file on  archive that i tried to found but no videos as well as reference found ....

Comment: Please quick reply me, if any one know the answer

Comment: If by archive you mean a compressed file like a zip or rar, you cannot get one file out of it. As far as AWS is concerned it is one object and can only be downloaded as a whole.

Comment: Hello Mr. volkan It's possible

Comment: I meant in terms of native AWS support. Of course anything is possible with external tools. If you know how to do it with API calls please explain, until then no, there is no built-in support for that

Comment: I think that's may be impossible, but i am sure that this tool optimize the overall cost of glacier.

Comment: Sir, can you help me to active mfa on S3 on detail, on aws docs i do that they say, but unable to activate mfa...

Answer (score 0):

Yup, i found solution
There's tool or utility that provide solution to download specific portion of download file using "mtglacier". more information available on following link.
Thank you, Github
[enter link description here](http://github.com/vsespb/mt-aws-glacier)